# Scheme - sum of list

Tags: functional-programming, scheme

I'm trying to implement a function which calc sum of list  , its name is `sum` -

```
(define (sum elemList)
  (if
   (null? elemList)
   (+ (car elemList) (sum (cdr elemList)))
   0
  )
 )
```

The above implementation gives wrong result  , for example  -

```
> (sum (list 1 2 3 4 ))
0
```

What I did wrong here ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you swapped the *then* and the *else* part of the `if`:

```
(define (sum elemList)
  (if
    (null? elemList)
    0
    (+ (car elemList) (sum (cdr elemList)))
  )
)
```

In the original function, for every non-empty list, `0` is returned.

Comment: And for an empty list an error would be produced because it'd try to take the `car` and `cdr` of an empty list.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `apply`

```
(define (sum elemList) (apply + elemList))
```

Should give you the same results

Answer (score 0):

Please refer by this link for more details.
-http://groups.umd.umich.edu/cis/course.des/cis400/scheme/listsum.htm

```
(define(list-sum lst)
    (cond
((null ? lst)
    0)
((pair? (car lst))
    (+(list-sum (car lst)) (list-sum (cdr lst))))
(else
    (+ (car lst) (list-sum (cdr lst))))))
```

Comment: It is better to include important parts of the link in your answer as the link may break/change. Also add an explanation to what your code does.