# Sum all the numbers in a list of dotted pairs

Tags: list, scheme

I'm new in Scheme and I have a lot of problems to understand it.

If I have this list `'((a . 1) (c . 3) (b . 2))`, I will need to get the number 6.

I know how to do it with numbers instead of dotted pairs (get it from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15019955/68571)):

```
(define (sum elemList)
  (if
    (null? elemList)
    0
    (+ (car elemList) (sum (cdr elemList)))
  )
)
```

But, how can I get the sum of all numbers in a dotted pairs list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can do it:

```
(define (sum elemList)
  (if (null? elemList)
      0
      (+ (cdr (car elemList)) (sum (cdr elemList)))))
```

Simply take the `cdr` of the `car` of each element. With the `car` part you extract the first *pair* of the list, and with the `cdr` you retrieve the second element of that pair. We can even simplify it a bit:

```
(cdr (car elemList))
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
(cdar elemList)
```

But in Scheme we prefer to use built-in functions to compose solutions, so an even more idiomatic way to write it would be:

```
(define (sum elemList)
  (apply + (map cdr elemList)))
```

We take the `cdr` of each pair in the list, and then we add them all together. Short, nice and simple. Any of the above solutions will work as expected:

```
(sum '((a . 1) (c . 3) (b . 2)))
=> 6
```